# Как сгладить движущийся по canvas объект?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

По canvas движется объект: примитив или спрайт. Если скорость передвижения очень большая то в глаза начинает бросаться что объект отрисовывается только в определённыех точках, в которых он находится во время отрисовки кадра. FPS около 60, для крупных и медленных объектов это не актуально. А вот мелкие и быстрые объекты, размер которых намного меньше дистанции между положениями объекта в двух соседних кадрах это заметно. Какие наиболее правильные способы есть сделать это менее заметным, чтобы движения были более плавные? Поможет ли отрисовка шлейфа за объектом и если да, то что именно отрисовывать в этом шлейфе? Может использовать не шлейф а просто вытянуть объект вдоль траектории движения?

Comment: В первую очередь надо увеличивать число кадров в секунду, особенно если сейчас их меньше чем 60

Comment: Забыл дописать "при максимально возможном FPS". Отрисовка не сложная и FPS колеблется вокруг 60. Но при быстром движении размер которых значительно меньше дистанции между двумя кадрами скачки сильно заметны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шлейф (исчезающий след), размазанный или альтернативный спрайт для быстро движущегося объекта - отличные визуальные подсказки, откуда и куда что полетело.

В зависимости от ситуации, в качестве эффекта можно

- повторить тот же объект несколько раз с разной прозрачностью
- сжать текстуру объект до колонки в 1 пиксель и размазать её назад, опять же с прозрачностью
- задействовать цветные линии с плавным исчезновением
- поднять облачко "пыли" с места старта объекта (классический приём из мультфильмов)

И много чего другого.

Comment: Спасибо, значит я думал в правильном нарпавлении